# AngularJs destructuring $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, location, destructuring

Instead of using:

`const ref = $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host();`

i try to do it like this:

```
const { protocol, host } = $location;
const ref = protocol() + '://' + host();
```

but it does not seem to work. ( protocol() is not returning anything, same for host() )
However, if I try something like this:

```
const loc = {
    protocol: function(){
        return 'http';
    },
    host: function(){
        return 'example.com';
    },
};

const { protocol, host } = loc;

document.write(protocol() + '://' + host());
```

it works. Any ideea why?

Ps. Some sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/fn6sjdxr/), just uncomment the second line and it would not work anymore.

Comment: What's `$location`?

Comment: protocol() doesn't return anything but does it throw an error? Like `is not a function`?

Comment: @JackBashford https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: @Smytt If I try to simply return protocol without () it will return a function, If I console.log protocol() I don't get any error but it will print nothing. If you have an angularjs project you can make a quick test.

Comment: @paulalexandru can you create a running snippet which produces the error ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, check here https://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/fn6sjdxr/ just uncomment the second line and you will see that it would not work anymore

Comment: @paulalexandru if you see there's a error in console of browser clearly states the problem

Comment: You can bind those methods to `$location` to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

You loose reference to this when you de-structure methods,`$location.protocol` and `protocol` refer to different `this`

```js
let a = {
  myName : 'my name',
  nameLogger(){
    return this.myName
  }
}

let {nameLogger} = a

console.log( 'Hello ' + nameLogger())

nameLogger = nameLogger.bind(a)

console.log( 'Hello ' + nameLogger())
```

Comment: Let me understand, basically you can de-structure methods which does not contain the this keyword like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/rodcknxb/ right ? Is there any solution to de-structure methods which contain the this keyword?

Comment: @paulalexandru you can bind with `a`